# Editing Address book Programmatically - iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm able to add contact to address book now after adding the contact whil clicking on edit button the button should change as done how to handle ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AddressBook API for the iPhone is given in the [AddressBook Programming Guide for iPhone OS](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html). I'm not sure what you are asking because your question is not intelligible English; however, if there is something that you need to do with the AddressBook on the iPhone the answer is almost certainly given in the link.

Comment: hey thanx michael after adding a contact to the address book when i click on info bar it should return back to my application

Comment: link is broken.